# ¿Origen de "carmelita" como color?

Tags: etimología, diferencias-regionales, religión, colores

En mi país Cuba para referirnos al color marrón nosotros decimos *carmelita*.

He notado que por ejemplo en Colombia y México nunca me entendieron cuando lo mencionaba y tenía que decir color **café** o **marrón** para hacerme entender.

¿Cuál es el origen de *carmelita*? ¿Es usado en otras regiones?

Comment: Sin haber ido a Cuba yo crecí al norye de Boyacá y de niña siempre conocí el color carmelito

Answer (score 8, accepted):

En el DLE está el color que buscas:

> [**carmelita**](https://dle.rae.es/?w=carmelita)
>
> 3. (Por alus. al del hábito de los carmelitas). adj. Bol., Chile y Cuba. Se dice del color pardo, castaño claro o acanelado.

Como ves también se usa en Chile y Bolivia y el origen es el color del hábito que llevan la orden de las carmelitas.

Similarmente, [*franciscano*](https://dle.rae.es/franciscano) significa "Marrón semejante al del hábito de los franciscanos", y [*capuchino*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cappuccino#Etymology) solía significar un color en el siglo XVII, por el hábito de los capuchinos (y de allí el nombre del café, por su color parecido).

Answer (score 3):

Hace años también me sorprendí de que "carmelita" fuera una denominación "local". Ya sabía que venía del hábito usado por las hermanas de la orden Carmelitas descalzas.

Ahora me encuentro en Haifa, Israel, frente al monte Carmel. En su cima se encuentra la iglesia y el monasterio de Stella Maris, origen de las Carmelitas ("La Orden de los Hermanos de Nuestra Señora del Monte Carmelo" o Carmelitas). Así que ahí está el origen ancestral de la palabra: el monte Carmel que domina la ciudad de Haifa.

Comment: El nombre **Carmen** es muy importante y usado en mi país (Chile) por razones religiosas. Yo siempre pensé que derivaba del latín _carmen_ ("poema"). Y ahora me entero que se debe al Monte Carmelo. Muchas gracias @Rafael, me ha agradado leer esta respuesta.