# Translations of brown: 'café' or 'marrón'?

Tags: traducción, diferencias-regionales, colores

I have been studying Spanish off and on for many years. Most of the time I have been told '**café**' used to translate *brown*. However, my latest teacher says '**marrón**'.

Is one more appropiate in certain situations or countries?

Comment: Do you mean "color café"?

Comment: Hello, Vikki, welcome to this site. Could you include a full sentence using the term requested? In Spain, café is the beverage known as coffee in English. Nobody uses "brown" to order it. In relation with colors, café is a specific kind of brown.

Comment: Where are you studying Spanish? Where are your teachers from?

Comment: There are multiple ways to say "marrón" in Spanish. There's also "castaño" and "pardo".

Comment: Using coffee to refer to the color brown, is like using an apple to refer to the color red or green... it's simply a type. The translation for the color is **marrón**.

Answer (score 7):

The name of the brown color in Spanish is given by things that have the same color. When roasted, coffee beans have a nice brown color, which gave way to use ***[café](https://dle.rae.es/caf%C3%A9)*** as the name of that color in the countries where coffee beans are grown (mostly Hispanic America, as you can see in [fedorqui's answer](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/34797/12637)).

Here at the other side of the Atlantic we do not have coffee beans, so we used another thing to refer to the brown color: chestnuts. Chestnuts have a proper brown color so we used to refer to that color as ***[castaño](https://dle.rae.es/casta%C3%B1o)***, which comes from Latin *castanea* and this from Greek *κάστανα kástana*, so as you can see it is indeed an old word. You can find references to texts such as "un borrico castaño" or "un caballo castaño" in Spanish texts from the XVI century. We still use *castaño* to refer to the brown color, but mostly to refer to a hair color.

Nonetheless, the most used word here is ***[marrón](https://dle.rae.es/marr%C3%B3n)***, which we took from French *marron*, which also refers to chestnuts. This is a relatively new word. In the Royal Spanish Academy's first dictionary from 1734, the word *marron* referred to a kind of stone used to play *[marro](https://dle.rae.es/marro)*, a game. The first time the word *marrón* was recorded in the Academy's dictionary as the name of the brown color was less than 100 years ago, in 1925, although you can find cases starting from the last quarter of the XIX century:

[image: Marrón usage]

Of course, once in Spain we were aware of coffee beans and the beverage, we also started to say *color de café*, you can find texts in publications from Spain starting from the middle of the XVIII century using this expression, and the variation *color de café con leche* to refer to light brown. Nonetheless in Spain the word *café* is very seldom used to refer to the color. Of course the opposite is also true, nothing stops people in Hispanic America to use *marrón* for the color, in fact it seems to be the most used word in some of those countries.

Answer (score 4):

It indeed changes from country to country. In general we can say that:

- '**café**' / '**color café**' is not used in Spain and can be understood  in Hispanic America
- '**marrón**' is used in Spain

In any case, there are other words used for this, such as 'castaño' (see [What's the difference between 'marrón' and 'castaño'?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/18490/1674)) or 'carmelita' (in Cuba, as seen [¿Origen de "carmelita" como color?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/4933/1674) or Bolivia and Chile, according to [DAMER's entry](http://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=carmelita)).

The *Diccionario de americanismos* explains in [*café*](http://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=caf%C3%A9):

> **café**
>   adj. Mx, Gu, Ho, ES, Ni, CR, Pa, Cu, RD, Co, Ec, Pe, Bo, Ch, Py, Ar, Ur. De color café.

That is, that 'café' is an adjective to name the colour and it is used in these countries:

- Argentina
- Bolivia
- Chile
- Colombia
- Costa Rica
- Cuba
- Ecuador
- El Salvador
- Guatemala
- Honduras
- México
- Nicaragua
- Panamá
- Paraguay
- Perú
- República Dominicana
- Uruguay

So if we check against the [list of countries from Hispanic America](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hispanic_America) we see that it is used in all countries in Hispanic America but Venezuela.

Comment: I'm curious about the source of this. I grew up (and lived a good part of my adult life) in Argentina. I never use "café", nor I have heard people using it. In order of most to least used, I would say it's marrón (by a long shot the standard one), castaño, "color café", pardo; with the last two being very rare.

Comment: @MartinArgerami well DAMER lists places where this is used, but it is difficult to track how much. [Google Trend](https://trends.google.com/trends/explore?date=all&geo=AR&q=color%20café,color%20marrón) does not show much info if we filter by Argentina, but indeed shows a prevalence of 'marrón. We have a fundamental problem here consisting in that we don't know which are the sources they use (or at least [in Internet](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/21035/1674)) so this can vary a lot and can range from a neighbourhood to a full country. Also strange that just Venezuela is not in the list

Comment: @MartinArgerami I updated to make things clearer according to your comment: 'café' or 'color café' is understood in Hispanic America, while it is not in Spain. This is the _fragile_ certainty we have.

Comment: I'm from Argentina, and I can tell you we use the word **marron**. We do understand the use of coffee as a type of brown, but it is not common to refer to a color by type outside of a specialized context.

Answer (score 0):

I've noticed that *marrón* is used very seldomly in Mexico, where they prefer *café*. Of course there will be parts of Mexico where they use *marrón*, but it's mostly a regional thing just like soda, coke, and pop in the U.S.